# Можно ли из приложения iOS открыть ВКонтакте с уже забитым в поиске запросом с названием песни?

Tags: ios, swift, vkontakte-api

Можно ли в iOS из своего приложения открывать приложение ВК или браузер с ВК (если ВК не установлен), где в поиске музыки уже будет забит запрос с названием некоторой песни?

UPD: в android в приложении можно открыть ссылку вида: https://vk.com/audio?q=bambola и, если приложение VK установлено, то линк будет "перехвачен" и откроется то, что нужно - раздел "Моя музыка" в приложении VK с забитым запросом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как аналогичную манипуляцию проделать в iOS?

Comment: нет, такой фичи нет.

Comment: @NazarFazylov как в андроиде (см. upd вопроса) сделать никак нельзя?

Comment: попробуйте определить какой deep link у приложения вк. Думаю должно быть что-то похожее на vk://. Если удастся определить deeplink, попробуйте передавать такие же параметры как и на андроиде vk://audio ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем, на данный момент (август 2018), можно лишь открыть (диплинком) приложение vk на разделе "музыка" или "рекомендации музыки", но поиск музыки или поиск музыки с забитым запросом - нельзя

Answer (score 3):

Получить ссылку на экран музыки с поиском в iOS приложении VK скорее всего можно.

Конкретной ссылки я не смогу вам дать но могу подсказать в каком направлении можно двигаться.
Deep link у приложения вк - `vk://`

Прямая ссылка на музыку `vk://vk.com/audio`

Рекомендации музыки `vk://vk.com/audio?section=recoms`

Советую вам попробовать перебрать разные параметры: к запросу, к разделу музыки, возможно вам удасться угадать

Легко попробовать разные ссылки можно отправляя сообщения на iPhone с установленным на него приложением ВК

Comment: Адрес вида `vk://vk.com/audio` введённый в Safari предлагается открыть в VK приложении если оно установлено. Только что проверил на iPhone.

Comment: можно открыть (диплинком) приложение vk на разделе "музыка" или "рекомендации музыки", но поиск музыки или поиск музыки с забитым запросом - у меня так и не получилось (